# In python why reference a value inbetween the percent sign and s of a string format

Tags: python, string-formatting

Think I have kind of figured the answer to my question out while writing which is good, though it would be good to hear a more informed explanation of what is happening!

At first I thought `%(module)s` superfluous, but now I think it references the newly created dictionary value `obj.__name__` because `('%s' % dict(module=obj.__name__))` would not add anything to the string?

```
if isinstance(obj, types.ModuleType):
        return ('generated/%(module)s.html#module-%(module)s' %
                dict(module=obj.__name__))
```

Comment: Are you asking "how does it work/what does it mean?", "why is it being done in the code that you've posted?", or "why is it done in the general case?" In the general case, it performs a lookup in the dictionary object associated with the string for the key in the parens.

Comment: Was asking in general.. your answer cleared things up for me perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code

```
'generated/%(module)s.html#module-%(module)s' % dict(module=obj.__name__)
```

a lookup in the dictionary object associated with the key in the parens is performed, and the corresponding `%()s` placeholders are substituted with the value from the dictionary.

The reason that the code posted goes to the trouble of creating a dictionary is so that the key `module` can be referenced multiple times in the string. Otherwise you would have to write it like this:

```
'generated/%s.html#module-%s' % (obj.__name__, obj.__name__)
```

so the dictionary is being used to simplify the arguments used for string interpolation.

The more "modern" way to do it is with [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.format):

```
'generated/{0}.html#module-{0}'.format(obj.__name__)
```

Here the `{0}` is a placeholder for the first argument passed to `format()`, all instances of which will be substituted.

Or you can used named parameters:

```
'generated/{module}.html#module-{module}'.format(module=obj.__name__)
```